# When coding in Python, how do I achieve guarantees of correctness similar to those I get with Haskell's type system?

Tags: python, types

Using Haskell's type system I know that at some point in the program, a variable must contain say an Int of a list of strings. For code that compiles, the type checker offers certain guarantees that for instance I'm not trying to add an Int and a String.

Are there any tools to provide similar guarantees for Python code?

I know about and practice TDD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any static analysis tools for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-for-python)

Comment: The type system in Haskell isn't really a guarantee of correctness in general.  It's quite a localized concept of "correct", since it's limited to just "expected type".  And in Python "expected type" is often too limiting.  It's easy to write a Python function which can handle any numeric type, including types not defined when the function was written.

Comment: This questions got 1000 of duplicates on SO. in short, you do, in python you use duck typing. Search for duck typing.

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer is "not really". While tools like [PyLint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint) (which is very good BTW) will give you a lot of help and good advice on what constitutes good Python style, that isn't exactly what you're looking for and it certainly isn't a real substitute for things like HM type inference.

There are some interesting research projects in this area, notably Gradual Typing by [Jeremy Siek and colleagues](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~siek/) and some really interesting ideas like the [blame calculus](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/blame.html) of Wadler and Findler.

Practically speaking, I think the best you can achieve is by using some sensibly chosen runtime methods. Use the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) to test the type of an object (but remember to be true to Python's duck typing and so on). Use `assert` statements liberally. Or (possible 'And') use something like Design by Contract using [decorators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Pre-.2BAC8-Post-Conditions). There are lots of ways to implement these idioms, but this is typically done on a per-project basis. You may want to think about whether and how such methods affect the performance and resource usage of your programs, if this is critical for you. There have, however, been some efforts to [standardise](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0316/) techniques like DBC for Python, but these haven't (yet) been pushed into the cPython trunk. Here's hoping though :)

Answer (score 2):

Python is dynamic and **strongly typed** programming language. What that means is that you can define a variable without explicitly stating its type, but when you first use that variable it becomes bound to a certain type.

For example,

`x = 5` is an integer, and so now you cannot concatenate it with string, e.g. `x+"hello"`

Comment: That's exactly my issue. Doing `x=5;x+"hello"` will cause a run time error. Are there any Python static analysis tools that can find errors like this without running the code?

Comment: may be you check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470/are-there-any-static-analysis-tools-for-python